# How do I display something I enter in a JOptionPane on the JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, joptionpane

What I want to do is when I input something in JOptionPane, say, APPLES. I want to display it as APPLES in the JFrame. Now, if I want to input CATS next, it'll appear in the JFrame together with the APPLES.

It should look like this: APPLES CATS

And when I input more, it just displays and displays. The only way I know how to do it is to use setText for JLabel, but it's only displaying ONE word. How do I display ALL of the words I input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but it's only displaying ONE word

Hoping that you are getting word written in JOptionPane in JFrame, try this:

```
jLabel.setText(jLabel.getText() + " " + strGotFromJOptionPane);
```

Here `strGotFromJOptionPane` is the text you got from JOptionPane.

Comment: What is strFromJOptionPane? Is it a method? I'm going to try it now :) Thanks!

Comment: @alicedimarco No. It is the text you got from JOptionPane.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:
`myLabel.setText(myLabel.getText() + " " + myTextField.getText());`

Answer (score 3):

`JTextArea` has an [`append(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#method_summary) method.  It is a multi-line component that might be more appropriate for displaying a list of strings.  Or, for that matter, a `JList`, or `JTable` might be better suited to displaying the user input.

Comment: Well, I have tried using this for adding my input in a JList, but I also want to do it in a JLabel :)

Comment: @HarryJoy  I think only the OP can decide what is best based on their particular use-case.  So, not so much 'better', as 'alternative'.  ;)