# How do I remove multiple labels from a panel?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlist, jlabel

In reference to this: [How do I display something I enter in a JOptionPane on the JFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8323137/how-do-i-display-something-i-enter-in-a-joptionpane-on-the-jframe)

I've made a JList which also outputs what I've inputted, and it displays on the JPanel as JLabels, as what I've done using the link. However, how do I remove the respective JLabels this time? Thanks so much to anyone who will help!

Edit:
What I want to do is when I click the remove button in my JList, the label on the panel will also be removed.

Comment: I'm not sure adding a label per entry is a good idea. Maybe you should just add one label and set the text to be a concatenation of the list entries.

Comment: If I concatenate everything into a label, wouldn't that be removing everything all at once? D: What if I want to choose what to remove?

Comment: No you just remove from the list and update the label's text. You don't remove the label itself.

Comment: But I want to remove from the label xD lol sorry. I've already done removing things from the JList :)

Comment: Well, that's what I said: after removing entries from the `JList` just _update_ the label and you're done. Do the same when adding entries. There's no need to directly add/remove content to/from the label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll add an answer to provide some code since I have the feeling my comments are misunderstood.

First, if it isn't necessary, don't use a label per list entry but use one label whose contents is a concatenation of the list entries. Then update the label's text whenever the list changes.

Basically, you have a method like this:

```
private void updateLabel() {
   StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
   //this assumes listModel is a DefaultListModel and doesn't contain null values
   //adapt for other list models and add any necessary checks
   for( Object entry : listModel.toArray() ) {
     text.append( entry.toString()).append(" ");
   }
   label.setText( text.toString() );
}
```

Then add a listener to your list model:

```
listModel.addListDataListener( new ListDataListener() {      
  public void intervalAdded(ListDataEvent e) {
     updateLabel();
  }

  public void intervalRemoved(ListDataEvent e) {
     updateLabel();
  }

  public void contentsChanged(ListDataEvent e) {
     updateLabel();
  }
});
```

Thus, when you change something in the list the label would be updated automatically.

Comment: Wow. I'm gonna go try this out. Thanks so much!

Comment: I got it! You're so awesome! At first I got a nullpointerexception but I edited my code and voila :D Thanks so much! Lifesaver!

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:

```
String stringToRemove = "CATS";
jLabel.setText(jLabel.getText().replace(stringToRemove, "");
```

If you have say a `JLabel` set to: `"CATS DOGCATS APPLE"` it will change to `" DOG APPLE"` after removing the `CATS` string

Comment: What if I want to remove a different word based on what I've highlighted in the JList? D: Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

1) put there [JPopupMenu](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html) rather than [JOptionPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

2) add [List Selection Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html) to [JList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html), set Selection Model

3) check if `SelectedIndex` > -1, if passed then `removeItem(s)` from `JList` or from `ListModel`

4) better would be add `JList Items` to the [DefaultListModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#creating)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for a ListModel. When you implemented it, you can easily add/remove items.

For example:

```
// adding
listModel = new DefaultListModel();
listModel.addElement("Jane Doe");

list = new JList(listModel);

// removing (the selected item)
int index = list.getSelectedIndex();
listModel.remove(index);
```

For further information see the [Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#mutable).